# Adding a space in between underscores

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a hangman game right now and a requirement is to use underscores to display the letters.

So far for my code I have this:

```
char[] guessWord = new char[word.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < guessWord.length; i++)
    guessWord[i] = '_';
System.out.println(guessWord);
```

the output looks like this: `_____`, but I want it to make it look like this: `_ _ _ _ _`

I'm not sure how to insert that space in between. Any advice?

Comment: You'll learn a lot more by actually trying something and asking for help once you get stuck rather than not even trying.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just print the space in your for loop

```
char[] guessWord = new char[word.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < guessWord.length; i++){
    guessWord[i] = '_';
    System.out.print(guessWord[i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```